# how to access the data from request object for post call? - I am making a post call for lumen app

Tags: lumen

I have tried to log the request object from the post call made with postman. I have not sending the post data in url but as json body. as we send in angular 2.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        \LOG::info($request);
    }
```

and i get the following log

```
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:   no-cache
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  475
Content-Type:    application/json
Host:            localhost:8003
Origin:          chrome-extension://
Postman-Token:   42a2a660-b779-05d1-4fd7-
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36

------WebKitFormBoundaryc7vTNl95ddxp5j0y
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

dsfsreterter
------WebKitFormBoundaryc7vTNl95ddxp5j0y
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

sddfsdfgsdtret
------WebKitFormBoundaryc7vTNl95ddxp5j0y
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category"

sdfsdgbtretetr
------WebKitFormBoundaryc7vTNl95ddxp5j0y
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="published_on"

2005-2-2
------WebKitFormBoundaryc7vTNl95ddxp5j0y--
```

now how will I access the data i am getting in the post body.

I tried to access these ways it is not working.

```
  \LOG::info($request->input('name'));
  \LOG::info($request->get('name'));
  \LOG::info($request->request->get('name'));
  \LOG::info($request->all());
    \LOG::info($request->input('description'));
    \LOG::info($request->input('category'));
    \LOG::info($request->input('published_on'));
```

please help me to access the data form request object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all thank for looking into my problem. I found the mistake i made. which was not a mistake but a bug in lumen.

I was sending the post body like below

```
{'name':'gtg', 'description':'frs', 'category':'csd', 'published_on':'1955-5-5'}
```

Now I made the changes like below . the double quote is correct way of giving json in post body. but single quote was not accepted by lumen. it is a bug  from lumen.

```
{"name":"gtg", "description":"frs", "category":"csd", "published_on":"1955-5-5"}
```